# A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer

Every once in a while, which some regularity, somebody on SO completely misreads a question (or is just generally confused or insane or on drugs, or whatever) and posts an answer that has *absolutely nothing* to do with the question.  If you've been on SO for a while, you've probably seen something like this — a user asks:

> Is `i += f(++i);` undefined behavior in C++?

and someone responds:

> You need to use jQuery.click() on the checkbox.

Also with some regularity, these "answers" often get flagged as Not An Answer.  Sometimes this works, and the answers get deleted in the Low Quality Posts review queue (or by [a ♦ mod going above and beyond their duty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286043/why-was-my-not-an-answer-flag-declined-as-having-no-evidence#comment155113_286045)), but more often than not, such flags get declined with a terse message that "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it", or perhaps that "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Also quite regularly, the confused flagger then posts on Meta asking why the hell their flag got declined:

- [Sanity check on NAA flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/sanity-check-on-naa-flag/224452#224452)
- [Irrelevant, but not incorrect answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266096/irrelevant-but-not-incorrect-answer)
- [Why was my last flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267984/why-was-my-last-flag-declined)
- [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)
- [Disputed not an answer flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270710/disputed-not-an-answer-flags)
- [NAA-flag was disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272213/naa-flag-was-disputed)
- [Does answering the wrong question make an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273029/does-answering-the-wrong-question-make-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- [Reasons for declined not-an-answer flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276124/reasons-for-declined-not-an-answer-flag)
- [Is this really an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284044/is-this-really-an-answer)
- [Why was my "not an answer" flag declined as having no evidence?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286043/why-was-my-not-an-answer-flag-declined-as-having-no-evidence)
- ...[*et cetera*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/265552), [*et cetera*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declined-flags+not-an-answer), [*et cetera*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/declined-flags+not-an-answer)

In many of these cases, the users involved seem to have chosen the NAA flag based on the flag description, which currently says (emphasis mine):

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not attempt to answer *the* question.** It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

For a few examples, see these [highly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined#comment76076_268369) [upvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined#comment76165_268378) [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286043/why-was-my-not-an-answer-flag-declined-as-having-no-evidence#comment155099_286045).

The problem is that, even though it has been clearly explained on Meta several times that [mods do not (automatically) see the question when going through NAA flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276162/add-a-low-quality-posts-button-to-delete-answer-because-it-doesnt-answer-the-qu/276197#276197), and will therefore tend to [reject any flags for answers the look like they're answering *some* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/sanity-check-on-naa-flag/224452#224452), this is not obvious from the flag description at all.  Since most users will never see those Meta posts unless they're pointed to them, there will always be people flagging answers as NAA because they answer *some other question than what was asked*.

That is, unless we change the flag description.  There have been [extensive proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224167/proposal-for-making-the-meaning-of-not-an-answer-flags-clearer) for overhauling the NAA flags before, but I'd like to propose just a very simple, almost trivial change: **replace "the question" with "a question"** (and maybe "does not attempt" with "does not look like an attempt").

The new NAA flag description would thus read (changes in bold):

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not **look like an** attempt to answer **a** question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

This should bring the flag description much better in line with how NAA flags are actually being handled by mods.

---

Of course, there is a risk that this could swing too far in the other direction — for example, if the OP was asked in a comment to clarify their question, and mistakenly posted their clarification as an answer, a new flagger might perhaps think that such an "answer" doesn't qualify for an NAA flag under this new description (because it *does* answer the question posed in the comment).  That said, I don't think this is a serious issue:

- We have a lot of flaggers, and the experienced ones among them will still know that it qualifies.  It's probably better for the less experienced ones to flag slightly too little than too much.
- If it's obvious that the answer doesn't belong here (as *should* be the case for real NAA flags), most users will find *some* way of reporting it.  They might occasionally end up flagging such answers as VLQ, or as "other", but that has little effect on the eventual outcome.
- If someone is entirely deterred from flagging a non-answer because of this change, *and* even if no-one else comes along to flag it, it will still likely get downvoted (or at least will *not* get upvoted), pushing it below actual answers.  If it doesn't get flagged or downvoted *at all*, that probably means that the whole thread is tumbleweed territory, anyway (and likely to be eventually cleaned away by the roomba).

In the end, it's just a few words in an obscure dialog that most SO users will never even see.  But I think this change would save a few of those users some frustration and headache, and save us from having to re-hash this issue on Meta quite so often.

Comment: If it's undefined behavior, *anything* can happen, including having a jQuery API the user can use.

Comment: jQuery doesn't need UB to happen anyway. jQuery *is*. Or, should I say, `jQuery().is()`.

Comment: I'd +1—the OP clearly should have been using Boost::jQuery.

Comment: The text feels contradictory to me: First you note that "mods do not (automatically) see the question ..." implying that a NAA flag should not require looking at the question, but then go on to note that "... a new flagger might perhaps think that such an "answer" doesn't qualify for an NAA flag under this new description ...", referring to a response to a comment posted as a new answer, implying that those _should_ be NAA flagged. If mods should not be expected to look at the question, how would they know if the answer tries to answer the question or just some comment?

Comment: I really think the problem here is not the wording of that text but the general attitude toward NAAs. It makes no sense to keep around answers that have nothing to do with the questions they are posted on. We'll just wind up with a situation where "There are probably too many sheep standing on your server" qualifies as an answer to "How do I add these numbers together?" Perhaps we could let mods see the question _and_ the answer? I think that would resolve this in a sensible way. Or perhaps NAA flags could be handled by the community instead of by diamond mods?

Comment: @JLRishe: A new mod UI is in the works, but we haven't heard an ETA or seen so much as a mockup of what it might look like. At least it's good to know they're working on revamping the UI for us.

Comment: @JLRishe NAA flags *are* handled by the community, mods just have the ability to beat the community to the punch and respond anyway.  Mods are also shown a certain subset of posts that the community either can't handle, or that are contentious among the community's responses.  That said, the primary community response to answers like these is simply voting, not flagging.  If these answers all have a score of -10 it doesn't matter much if they're deleted or not.

Comment: @Servy I can't agree with that. Signal to noise ratio is critical, and it has destroyed many a prior Internet resource.

Comment: Why do mods not look on the question when deciding whether an answer is an answer or not? This does not make much sense. They should have a look.

Comment: @Trilarion Because what the question is is irrelevant when determining if a post as *an* answer.  Remember, mods are not there to judge the technical accuracy or quality of an answer.  If the post isn't an answer at all, a mod can delete it, and to know that an answer is asking a new question, commenting on another post, etc. doesn't require looking at the question.

Comment: @Servy I think it should be an answer to the question, everything else would not make a lot of sense. Just have a look at the most upvoted answer here.

Comment: @Trilarion But the point is that mods are not subject matter experts.  It is not their place to judge whether or not an answer *correctly* answers the question asked, to understand exactly what the question is asking, or whether or not the answerer seems to understand the question.  3 10k users can vote to delete the answer if it has a negative score, if they feel that it really is that bad.

Comment: @Servy Ok, that clarifies the matter. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: How about another flag altogether, something like "this answer is unrelated to the question". Then this leaves little place for confusion any more

Comment: @Trilarion not sure, but you should read Gilles [comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%e2%86%92#comment156539_286270)

Comment: @Braiam I had read it already. I upvoted the other comment of Gilles right below the one you linked.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

When you start an animation, you need to let control return back to the system in order to see it perform the animation. Inserting a `sleep` is almost never the right thing to do in today's world of multi-threaded systems. It is certainly the reason that you are experiencing this issue.

Instead, you might consider doing something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<10 ; i++){
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(i * 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Call animation function
  });
}
```

---

Given that your sleep time is the same as your intended animation duration, it looks like you're just trying to repeat your animation, though. Instead, try just adding this line and removing the loop:

```
[move setRepeatCount:10];
```

You'll also need to instantiate the object and actually add the animation to the layer.

```
CABasicAnimation *move = [[CABasicAnimation alloc] init];
[move setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[button.layer position]]];
CGPoint toLoc = [button.layer position];
// modify toLoc by +/-70px in x/y direction 
[move setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toLoc]];
[move setDuration:0.5];
[move setRepeatCount:10];
[button.layer addAnimation:move forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: This attempts to answer *a* question, so it shouldn't be deleted. Right?

Comment: This [point was also made](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/268413/revisions) on [a related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined).

Comment: @IanMacDonald Also, it is upvoted, meaning the community seems to see it as valuable content... ;-)

Comment: This is blatantly off-topic on meta, even if it doesn't qualify for NAA. -1

Comment: The original post does not contain a question. This is at least an answer.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: The original post is not supposed to contain a question.  It is tagged [tag:feature-request]

Comment: In all seriousness, like I commented elsewhere, this is why the canned NAA flag is reserved for content that is *unequivocally* not an attempt to answer *any* question in a way that makes sense on the site, *no matter the context*. "Thanks!" for example is not an answer to *any reasonable question* except "How do you express gratitude?" which would be off-topic on the site anyway - and besides, the proper way of formulating *that* as an answer would be "You thank the person" or somesuch. I would hope that the community has no trouble recognizing such answers.

Comment: While it is said time and again that it is not a moderator's place to judge the technical merits of an answer, it is perfectly fine to raise a custom flag, say something like "this appears to be a random clipboard dump and not an actual attempt at an answer" and we will handle it accordingly. The key here is context - a random clipboard dump could either be someone posting a random form for no apparent reason, *or* it could simply be an extremely poorly-formatted attempt at a code-only answer to the question at hand - we don't know, and that is up to the flagging user to explain it to us.

Comment: We cannot judge an answer that is flagged as "not an answer" when the only information that we see, that is, the answer alone as well as the question title, suggests otherwise that the answer could in fact be an answer. That doesn't mean we rely solely on a custom flag to determine whether the answer should be deleted - after all, the flagging user could have been mistaken - but it gives me a reason to further investigate the answer whereas NAA means "you don't *need* to know, just delete it".

Comment: @BoltClock “We cannot judge an answer that is flagged as "not an answer" when the only information that we see, that is, the answer alone as well as the question title” I don't get this. In the flag dashboard, all it takes is one click to show the question body, and I routinely do this when a NAA flag isn't immediately obvious. Or do you SO guys get a different interface from the rest of the network?

Comment: @Gilles: Then that should have been "We cannot do so without having to investigate further". The NAA flag is designed to be obvious. You shouldn't be using it for non-obvious stuff.

Comment: @BoltClock “The NAA flag is designed to be obvious.” Yes, obvious **in context**. You sometimes need to look at the question to figure out if the post should be deleted altogether, or converted to an edit, or converted to a comment. Looking at the question is sometimes necessary for an NAA flag. Custom flags are for non-obvious cases, not for a jQuery answer on a C++ question. This kind of case *should* be a canned flag that feeds into a delete queue (combining VLQ and NAA) and not handled by mods at all.

Comment: @BoltClock I think that times of _no-context-needed_ rule have gone when Shog established "castle" guidance, expecting moderators to take a look at the question to decide if NAA on a link only answer is valid or not: "one valid exception to this rule... when the question is kinda asking for bad answers". After the system has eroded like that, we better make it explicitly clear that irrelevant "answers" either should not be flagged or that moderators are expected to refer question when acting on NAA flags cast on these

Comment: I never thought I'd actually laugh at something I saw on SO.

Comment: What question would this attempt to answer? If you have to make up a question for this to be an answer, I'd argue it's not an answer at all. Just my opinion but an answer to me implies a solution to a question. Without a question, it's not an answer so much as it's a general statement, in which case it's off topic and should be deleted.

Comment: It obviously attempts to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549103/cannot-see-a-cabasicanimation-when-called-from-within-a-for-loop . However, I don't see why posts made here are considered "Answers" if the original post is not considered a "Question". By posting a non-question, the original poster has degraded this system into a reddit-like forum where upvoted "Answers" bubble to the top.

Comment: By _"here"_ I'm assuming you're meaning meta.stackoverflow.com? or stackoverflow.com in general? Either way, it doesn't matter because I agree with you. If a question is stated in a non-question manner, then by definition it's not a question and therefore violates the _"Q"_ of the site's Q&A model. I'm simply arguing that posting a non-answer to a non-question doesn't justify the answer or make it right. It just means both the question and the answer are in violation of the Q&A model.

Comment: My usage of "here" refers to "Answers" made to this specific "Question". There are many legitimate questions on Meta. This particular "Answer" is actually intended more as a way to highlight the pitfalls of the existing system when it comes to non-answers and non-questions.

Answer (score 38):

I think you're overstating the severity of the problem here.

Yes, there are a fair number of questions about flag dismissals; you've collected a nice list. However, only a minority of these fall into the "JavaScript answer to C++ question" category; there are multiple reasons why NAA flags get declined.

This is the UI for declining a flag:

[image: flags should not be used to indicate technical innaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer]

...and that first option is the one that *should* be used to decline most flags that concern an incorrect - but otherwise well-formed - answer.

Why wouldn't we want to rely on moderators to remove incorrect or even *blatantly off-topic* answers? Because things aren't always so clear-cut:

- **Answers that cover the same API as the one being used in the question may still be valuable, even if they're written in a different language.** The classic example is probably C# answers to VB.NET questions, but you can also observe this in C++ answers to .NET questions concerning WinAPI calls, JavaScript answers to jQuery questions, etc.
- **Answers to X-Y questions may address a different layer of the stack in order to provide a better solution than the one the asker thought he needed.** This can include PHP answers to JavaScript questions, JavaScript answers to Ruby questions, C# answers to SQL Server questions...

It's not always enough to read the question, it's not even enough to *understand* the question - to correctly evaluate these answers, you need a solid understanding of the *answer* and the ability to judge whether or not it might actually solve the underlying problem. Whether a moderator or reviewer is able to do this is impossible to predict.

...and even if the person handling the flag does understand the technologies involved, this can all fall apart if the question itself is unclear. At least one of your examples involved a lousy answer to a *terrible* question - in this situation, all bets are off; realistically, the moderator is probably better off closing or deleting the question and ignoring the flagged answer.

#### Reflecting all this in the flag description

So the problem here isn't so much that moderators can't or won't handle blatantly off-topic answers, it's that the cases where they don't are usually a lot less clear-cut than the flagger realizes. That's *why* we have decline reasons, and why we *notify flaggers* of declined flags - so that they can develop a better understanding of how these things are perceived and learn to use the system more effectively.

In other words, these discussions aren't so much an indication of a serious problem as they are the results of an educational tool that was long overdue. The volume of these complaints are a drop in the bucket compared to the number of flags declined, the volume of which is similarly minuscule when compared to those that are acted on or even those which are disputed.

I'm reticent to make any changes here that would discourage people from flagging *truly* egregious violations: folks posting the first Google result without any indication that it relates to the question *whatsoever*, auto-generated spam, etc. Such answers are a disease, and not one that should be ignored. If that means the occasional dispute over an edge-case, so be it - there are literally thousands of success stories to go with every one of them, and each small success makes reading Stack Overflow a better experience than the forums that don't bother going after these.

That said, there's a change I *would* love to see to this flag text, that might make some small difference here: stop using the word "answer" to refer to both the post itself *and* the action of addressing the asker's problem:

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not address the problem being asked about**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

And then couple that more explicitly to the default decline reason by rewording that as well:

> this answer appears to address the asker's problem. Use downvotes to indicate inaccurate or entirely wrong answers. For subtle forms of abuse, choose "other" and explain the problem in detail.

I think the *combination* of these two changes would serve to reduce a lot of the confusion surrounding these flags, without greatly changing the implied purpose.

Comment: "why we notify flaggers of declined flags". Well, that needs lots more work. At the moment one cannot even sort the flags by the time they were processed instead of the time they were cast. For bonus points, if sorted by time of processing, it should also indicate the flag-ban-window...

Comment: "realistically, the moderator is probably better off closing or deleting the question and ignoring the flagged answer." that would be a fair compromise, and if I see a doggy answer to a doggier question, obviously my main concern would be trying to close the question quickly. Can that be added somewhere in the guidance? Because sometimes that path isn't obvious for the flaggers.

Comment: _"In other words, these discussions aren't so much an indication of a serious problem as they are the results of an educational tool that was long overdue."_ The educational tool is an improved flag description, no?

Comment: _"The volume of these complaints are a drop in the bucket compared to the number of flags declined"_ To me that smells of an entirely different conversation. If nothing else you're basically admitting that a ton of NAA flags get declined, which only supports the notion of stopping NAA flag abuse in its tracks.

Comment: It seems like your proposed wording might actually lead to more such instances, because it refers to _the_ question at hand, which is not relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - By "educational tool", I believe Shog9 is referring to the recently enabled warning / ban system on declined flags. Prior to that, few people even noticed that their flags were being declined, but the warnings have been extremely effective at making people pay attention to these. That's great from an educational perspective (turning bad flaggers to good ones), but it has led to more arguments on Meta as people notice declined flags they don't agree with. Like airplane crashes, these complaints become a spectacle and make things seem more frequent than they are.

Comment: @Brad: Oh okay I wasn't aware of a new system. That may be it then

Comment: I like your suggestion in general, but not the wording. I mean, a philosophical diatribe may be addressing a question without trying to answer it... so I'd make it "does not try to provide a solution to the problem being asked about" or something similar.

Comment: Do we really need a predefined flag for philosophical diatribes, @einpoklum?

Comment: @Shog9: No, which is why I made my suggestion.

Comment: "I think you're overstating the severity of the problem here." Maybe the real problem is how much we argue about it on Meta, then. A little more clarity in the description would go a long way toward solving *that* problem. I think it's unlikely that your new wording will do so, since it still doesn't draw a very hard line between when to use and when not to use the flag. Understanding that anything that even remotely looks like an answer should not be flagged as NAA would still be difficult to get from it. I doubt that would be my impression if I weren't aware of the proper usage from Meta.

Comment: The jQuery vs JS thing was a joke… right?

Comment: [I wish](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275258/should-we-recommend-a-jquery-solution-when-javascript-is-equally-short-easily-im), @bjb568

Comment: *scurries back to localhost and hides*

Comment: I would love to see the change proposed at the bottom of your answer. Is there a reason why it was never implemented?

Comment: Waiting on a few other things before revisiting this, @TylerH. One was the redesign of the flag history page (recently completed) allowing better examination of flag decline reasons. The other is a redesign of the moderator's flag UI to provide more context; that's still TBD.

Comment: Ping, moderator's flag UI has been updated? How up is in the priority list?

Comment: Still no updates?

Comment: @Shog9 Any update or ETA on an update regarding the mod flag UI (now that it's been >3 years)?

Comment: There's a big change to the flag UI ready to be alpha tested starting today, @TylerH. So... yeah, that took a while. But making some progress.

Comment: @Shog9 That's awesome, though. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 19):

I think this is a great idea, in principle. It really gets my goat up when people cling stubbornly to their misconception of the flag so, if we can make it easier for them to understand then we'll all be better off for it.

However, I'm not crazy about your proposed wording. Here's mine:

> This was posted as an answer, but instead it discusses the question, asks a follow-up question, suggests an edit, or is otherwise misplaced. It should have been written as a comment; in its current form, it could be deleted.

Comment: Agree except for "it could be converted to a comment". I recall several discussions with mods saying they basically never do that; the answer is either deleted or stays.

Comment: @l4mpi: The author of the non-answer is free to do so, though.

Comment: Best wording I've heard so far.

Comment: `but instead it ...` ... lets avoid enumerating a range of possibilities.

Comment: @BrettCaswell: Usually I'd agree, but the whole point of this question is that the flag reason needs to be precise and clear. People have misunderstood it, so this is no time to be succinct and ambiguous!

Answer (score 13):

I actually prefer the current wording to your proposed change, and your post highlights exactly why. A lot of NAA flags get declined because when a mod reads them, they look like perfectly valid answers. In a [previous discussion on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/1448943), this was posted:

> What mods are looking for when they see a "Not an Answer" flag:
>
> - Attempts to communicate with another user.
> - Using the answer space to ask a question.
> - The OP posting an answer to clarify their question or add additional detail.
> - Attempts to bump the question as in "I'm having the same problem."
> - "Thanks," [I like turtles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y), and similar noise.

To me, this is the problem. What mods *should* be looking for on NAAs are *things that do not attempt to answer the question*. The really scary part was at the bottom of that same answer:

> **Pro Tip:** Mods do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags. If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from the question's perspective, do not use a "Not an Answer" flag on it.

My question here is simple: how on earth are mods supposed to know whether something might be a valid answer without knowing what the question is?

I think the best thing that could be done to make NAA flagging work better is to make it clear to mods that they *need to read the question*. If that means rewording the flag description to say "does not attempt to answer **this** question" or something like that, then I'm all for it. If anyone has ideas for on how it could be achieved by other means, then those are probably worth looking at too.

Comment: Also means redesigning the user interface moderators use to process these flags. Still a better idea than a wishy-washy flag description.

Comment: `how on earth are mods supposed to know whether something might be a valid answer without knowing what the question is?` Why *would* they need to look at the question to evaluate if the post is any of the things listed?  An answer that says, "thanks for providing a great answer" is Not An Answer regardless of what the question is.  The question is 100% irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy: Which just means that mods have to use their discretion in deciding if the reason for the flag is obvious just from the answer, or they should peek at the question for neccessary context.

Comment: @Deduplicator No, that doesn't mean that.  You would need to come up with common use cases for posts that really are NAA but that can only be determined to be NAA by looking at the question.  I asked for said examples and have yet to be given any.

Comment: @Servy An answer that says "Try clearing the DNS cache on your server" *might* be a valid answer... but if the question is "why do I get odd results when doing floating-point arithmetic in C++?", then that's definitely Not An Answer. In this case, the mod **really** needs to read the question. An answer, as an abstract concept, is predicated on there being a question. The validity of such an answer cannot be fully assessed without knowledge of the question it claims to answer.

Comment: @anaximander That isn't Not An Answer.  That's a very low quality answer.  It's an answer that fails to adequately answer the question asked; it's not a post that isn't actually an answer.  The example you describe meets none of the criteria for the NAA flag, so that flag would be correctly declined, because whether the reviewer sees the question or not the post is *an* answer, even if it's a terrible one.  That said, people don't actually posts answers like that.  When posts fail to answer the question, it tends to be because questions are unclear and understanding them is hard.

Comment: @anaximander If you actually see an answer like that, a custom flag explaining the situation would likely be warranted, because it really is an exceptional case.  For the vast majority of *actual* cases where the answer fails to answer the question, a mod that likely isn't familiar with the subject is unlikely to be able to suitably judge the answer.  You should use votes to indicate that an answer fails to adequately answer the question asked.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to suggest two changes/additions to your proposal:

1. Use "any" instead of "a". This will put greater emphasis on the meaning you're trying to convey.
2. Do away with the "deleted altogether" part. The more I think about it, the more it seems way too broad. It's more likely to lead to incorrect usage of the flag than it is to provide any clarity. There's a lot of content that should be deleted but doesn't qualify for the flag.

After those, you're left with this:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to provide any answer to any question. It possibly should be an edit, a comment, or another question, or it may be off-topic for the site.

Comment: On the contrary, it may not be appropriate for the answer to become an edit, a comment or another questions. The answer may simply be off topic  or completely out of scope, in which case it should be deleted.

Comment: @War10ck Yes, but this wording doesn't exclude that possibility. Note that it says "possibly should be," much like the original. I think it's reasonable to assume that people will understand that there are other courses of action given the wording, while including the "delete" option just makes it seem broader than it really is. If you're concerned about that case, maybe adding, "or out of scope" or something similar would be appropriate. The point is to foster understanding about how the flag should be used. The current wording clearly doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: @War10ck I've attempted a change to more explicitly deal with that case. I'd appreciate your thoughts. I'm concerned that the reference to "off-topic" might be misconstrued, though, so I may try to improve this more later.

Comment: +1 to that. Just my opinion but I think you're new wording is very well done. It leaves the possibility that the answer or non-answer may just in fact be off topic and may not be appropriate on the site. I think it fills the gap where it doesn't fall into one of the first three categories so it just gets left on the site to be handled at a later time because an appropriate action cannot be determined (or maybe cannot be agreed upon by the community).

Answer (score 7):

Can’t this whole problem be mostly resolved, if people who raise such flags leave a short comment on the answer so that reviewers and moderators see *why* the answer was flagged? For example:

> I fail to see how this answer addresses the question’s problem in any way.

Also, this way authors of such answers get informed early and can either clarify how their answer relates to the question (if it actually does) or delete it (if they realise that they made a mistake) – not that I expect this to work very often.

Comment: Not unless they specify *why* or *how* it doesn't address the Question.

Answer (score -6):

The problem isn't the use or implementation of NAA. The flag itself is useless due to its unavoidable subjectivity. It should be replaced with:

**Junk**

> This answer is bascially spam but doesn't promote anything. It wouldn't meet answer standards anywhere on the site.

So this doesn't overlap with VLQ. VLQ goes out to non-mods in the area, to spread awareness and potentially solicit delete votes about misleading erroneousness or other fine grained content problems. The VLQ queue could potentially be improved by being fed to people participating in the relevant tags.

Conclusion: junk is just for the trash that isn't spam. Then I think everything is accounted for.

Comment: [A relevant well put answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268409)