# Should the "Not an answer" flag be split in two?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, not-an-answer

Been reading [a suggested wording change to the "not an answer" flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag) and related meta discussions (there are a *lot*).

It's obvious that there are two camps on this issue, each with a lot of voices. One says:

> "Not an answer" means something that is not an answer to any question. Doesn't matter what the question was. Mod should (probably) be able to accept/decline the flag without seeing the question.

The other says:

> We should be able to flag answers that clearly don't answer *the actual question*. They don't belong here, and very often the downvoting system doesn't clear them out in a timely manner, or at all.

And every time the issue comes up (usually "why was my flag declined?" meta questions), there's a lot of debate, usually with experienced mods arguing the former (on the basis that it is actually the intent of the flag, along with the fact that they shouldn't have to make a judgement call based on technical knowledge), and lots of other people arguing the other point, with people on both sides seeming to ignore that they're *both* useful points of view.

To me, this smacks of a dysfunctional debate.

- "*The water tastes bad*."
- "Then stop drinking out of the toilet."
- "*But I'm really thirsty and I should be able to drink*."
- "Yes, but it's a toilet."...

Maybe the solution is to install a drinking fountain?

Ok, I was never great at analogies, but should we have two different flags?

1. not any kind of answer to anything, clearly should be deleted *(mods should be able to clear this out with a 5-second glance)*
2. not an answer to *this* question *(might need a bit more thought to review)*

Comment: I think (2) is going to be problematic, because you need domain experts to review it instead of mods.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET potentially, but that might depend on how it's phrased. TBH, my main motivation is that I think (1) needs to exist without any ambiguity, but clearly there are a large number of people who think (2) needs to exist. Because it doesn't, they simply won't accept that they shouldn't use (1), and the debate rages on

Comment: So do we just fake everyone out and the (2) flags just go into nothingness?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET actually, I'll have to admit that I'm not 100% familiar with how the votes/mods/review queues relate to each other. I got the impression that "not an answer" can either be processed by voting, or headed off at the pass by a mod. If I'm wrong about that, it makes it harder. But if my impression is right, then my suggestion would allow mods to quickly deal with (1) while leaving (2) to due process

Comment: You are right. But reviewers aren't domain experts *either*. The only way I could see it would be a *new* queue thats open to silver/gold tag badge holders. That way domain experts are reviewing the "wrong" answers. Is that actually a good idea? I don't know, but its the only way I see *your* suggestion working.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET well, the "domain expertise" aspect is another part of the same debate. The (2) camp often argue that there are *some* answers that clearly don't answer *the* question, if you take the time to read the question, with mods arguing that they shouldn't have to read the question for "not an answer". Mods often suggest using a custom flag for (2) to keep (1) pure, so I guess my suggestion is akin to formalizing that

Comment: Reviewers [can restrict the domain](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wGK8s.png) easily enough, @BradleyDotNET.

Comment: I'm happy with the notion that this is what downvotes are for. Answers that are wrong, have misunderstood the question etc. Downvote and move on. I only think there's a particular pressing need to delete for particularly horrible answers, (spam/offensive/malicious/downright harmful) and otherwise just leave it be.

Comment: @Sobrique TBH I tend to mostly agree, however there are a large number of people who don't, and that to me indicates that either they need to be convinced (which isn't happening), or there's something wrong with the system.

Comment: I tend to agree with Brad Larson's answer, but I think you did an excellent job of summing up the perceived issue (I, too, have noticed the raging debate).  Some people nearly come to virtual blows ;).  One has to keep in mind, though, that Meta can be a bit of a crucible, and things that look huge on Meta may or may not be having a huge effect on the main site, as far as statistics go.

Comment: See also [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)  (Heck yes, but explain why.)  My take on it is that some questions **should *not* be answered**, so I don't really see a need for the 2nd reason.

Comment: Are you asking for an off-topic (in relation to the question) flag for answers?

Comment: What is bad to drink from the toilet? ;)

Comment: @canon something like that I guess

Comment: @DerGolem I'll have to admit I was speculating on that one; if you have some experience that disagrees, I will certainly bow to that ;)

Comment: I'll do that for 6 millions euro. Using a survival water purifier and after the toilet is empty and it has been cleaned accurately. :) Anyway, I've seen dogs doing that *for free*, unequipped, and survive.

Answer (score 25):

Before adding even more flagging options (we have plenty of them as it is), we should examine if this is even a problem worth addressing.

Hundreds of "not an answer" flags are processed each day. We see questions or complaints about these on Meta maybe once or twice a week at worst. As [Shog9 notes in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286366/19679), only a small fraction of the complaints gathered in your linked question would even be impacted by your proposed second flag option. You're talking one in a thousand to one in ten thousand "not an answer" flags that this might apply to.

As others have commented, do we even want this as an option? A flag like this would seem to imply a shift toward making moderators judge the technical merit of answers. For both practical reasons (there's no way we could have enough moderators with aptitude in all the areas covered by the site) and philosophical ones (do we really want a small group of people to judge what's correct and what's not), I find this troubling.

Also, frankly, I don't think it's needed to accomplish what you want. Most of the problems with poorly interpreted "not an answer" flags come from people using that and expecting us to understand the context in which they flagged it. For cases where a little more information is needed, people can easily use an "other" flag and write out why an answer needs to be immediately deleted.

We get these custom flags regularly right now, and they are far more helpful than any canned flag reason. Why add a flag option that would very rarely be used when you could just do that?

Comment: "a shift toward making moderators judge the technical merit of answers." Not necessarily; NAA flags already go to a review queue before moderators get to see them. That could plausibly be strengthened to show MkII NAA flags only to people reviewing with an appropriate [tag filter](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wGK8s.png).

Comment: You know, it's not unreasonable for a supposed-answer to be not-an-answer, but for this fact to be non-trivial to realize.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - At that point, wouldn't it make more sense to have "very low quality" encompass these, rather than "not an answer"? It's hard to get a good judge of this at present in review, because the Low Quality Posts review queue is currently overrun with questions that shouldn't be in there. Most of the "not an answer" flags are still falling to moderators to handle because the community isn't getting to them in under a day. If "very low quality" answer flags were exclusively handled by the community, maybe placing these kinds of answers in that category would be better.

Comment: I would agree that it probably isn't enough of a problem in order to implement a change which could possibly have its own issues. However I think the point on moderators judging the technical merit of questions misses the nuance of how off the wall the answer may be. In a question regarding a programming issue there is a difference between someone making an answer that subtly misses the point and something like "you should walk your dog every day". Which would not likely answer any question on this site at all but does answer something. should there perhaps be a distinction there?

Comment: I don't think it matters what we call it, but I agree that it makes sense to give the flags more time in front of regular users; they definitely don't represent an urgent matter.

Comment: I would argue what's said here strengthens the argument for a wording change. By clarifying that NAA is specifically for, "Does not even look like an answer," the only option left is to use an Other flag, and what you say here is that such an outcome is preferred. There could be an explicit note directing flaggers to use Other when dealing with an answer that needs to be seen in context.

Answer (score 7):

If it could be made concise, I'd support an adjustment to the flag text to allow a little more leeway to flag truly abominable answers stemming from an obvious and complete failure to address the question asked. But I wouldn't want to go all the way to pestering the mods with flags every single time someone misunderstands the question in any respect, and answers with a *non sequitur*.

There are surely not-an-answers that don't fit in either the category "not an answer to any question", nor the category "requires technical judgement to discern as a non-answer". They are an answer to *some* question, but not this one, and that doesn't require domain knowledge to determine. Leave aside the quality of this question: "how should I store a mapping from strings to integers in C++?"

> Use `std::map<string,int>` or `std::unordered_map<string,int>`

is an answer to the question and certainly should not be flagged.

> Hey, you don't say whether you need ordering or not, so we can't really answer.

is clearly not an answer. Flag.

> Use `java.util.HashMap`

is an answer to *a* question, but it doesn't take much specialist knowledge, at least not beyond what 95% of programmers have, to see that it isn't an answer to *the* question. It's an answer to a slightly different question that the answerer thought they read. It does of course require reading the question to see that there's anything wrong with it at all.

I see why mods don't want to have to deal with this stuff. It's a good faith attempt to answer the question perceived by the answerer, it's just horribly misguided, perhaps as the result of some kind of brain freeze. I see why it's the thin end of a wedge into not-an-answers that do require knowledge the mod doesn't have, or that require a time-consuming and subjective close read of the question to decide. Mods shouldn't have to do that. But I also see why people might feel a strong urge to flag it for deletion as worthless noise, especially if the author ignores comments pointing out why it's just woeful.

Basically, "an attempt to answer the question" (from the flag text) could be interpreted as "an attempt to figure out what the question means and answer it" (which this certainly is), or "an attempt to answer the question, how to store a mapping in C++" (which it isn't). It's a bit of an abstruse philosophical point, I'll grant you, but if I'm in an asylum believing I'm Napoleon on Elba, and try to row away, then is that "an attempt to escape Elba" or an "attempt to escape the asylum"? ;-)

Comment: What about the cases where the OP edits the question in response to an answer like this? Like for some reason, the question never mentioned any (in this case language) restriction, but then an answer reminded the OP to put in that restriction.  I admit this is a bad situation already.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: certainly I wouldn't want to waste moderator time clearing up answers to a question in the process of being edited for clarity. Sometimes a question is a moving target. That said, if the Java answer was highly-upvoted before the question was edited then surely site quality would be improved by either removing it or forcing the questioner to stick to what they originally asked. Downvoting by the long tail of later readers doesn't always deal with answers that *used* to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

It boils down to this, right?

- people want to flag the question, because they feel a downvote is not enough
- the name "not an answer" and its description don't make it clear enough, or are not visible enough, to dissuade users from doing so
- moderators can't/shouldn't need to judge the proposed flag

Would we still go with it, [@BradleyDotNET](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/bradleydotnet) formulated it like this:

> So do we just fake everyone out and the [not an answer to *this* question] flags just go into nothingness?

That's bad because it doesn't educate the users. **But what if we made education the sole point of the button?** I'm not a UX expert, but there are already mechanisms that prevent users from posting bad content, e.g. the "+1" comment filter. It's feedback that tells the user very directly, "you're doing it wrong", but apparently it's not deemed offensive.

So, my suggestion is: add a button with a suitable flag description. When a user presses it, tell them that downvoting is enough to make their voice heard, and link them to a help page that explains why that button can't go to an *actual* flag.

Comment: I like it. Kind of. The extra option for *experienced* flaggers would get in the way, but the educational value would be great. Also, you got the right citation this time :)

Comment: Users will quickly learn the current flag gets things deleted and this new decoy flag points them to a wall of text they won't read.  It's a cute idea, but I doubt it will help much.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The "why was my flag declined" questions come from users who are sincerely trying to choose the right flag. They see a multiple choice question and chose the most fitting flag because they don't think there is no such flag. If they are shown a better flag, they'll choose it. I don't think the next step is to go back and do something that is not the best fit, but maybe I'm too optimistic...

Answer (score -1):

The "solution" to the second option (does not answer this question) is to encourage the flagger to add a comment to the answer which would persuade the answerer to amend or rephrase their statement.

"Not an answer" remains as is.  Problem solved.

Except I don't have any appealing ideas of how the UI might do that.