# Low-rep flagging answer for deletion

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, vote-to-delete

I recently raised a Not An Answer flag on an old answer that had nothing to do with the question (or the question in its revision history, I checked).

My flag was:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

So, what should I do with this answer? I don't have high enough rep to delete it, but it's noise.

[The Questionable Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044739/2661831)

Comment: ...what answer?! Did you consider down-voting?

Comment: Why what? Why downvote it? Why *not* downvote it, if it isn't useful?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll go vote. :)

Comment: Search Meta for other questions about NAA. Basically, if it has the broad shape of being possibly an answer to something, flag it as low quality instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That seems like helpful information. I guess my bigger question is that the declined reason seems like it is bad to use flags to suggest deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer is technically *an* attempt at an answer. In the mod flag review queues, the question is not shown. As such, if the answer looks like *an* answer to *a* question that could possibly be asked on Stack Overflow, then the mod should (and probably will) decline the flag.

**See also:** [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag)

The current advice if an answer does not answer *the* question being asked is to downvote and if you really want to flag it then use a custom flag and make sure to describe thoroughly why the question does not attempt to answer the question being asked.

But, that said, it is best to not flag something if it can be dealt with by the community. This means downvoting, commenting letting the author know how their post is incorrect, and soliciting advice, downvotes or delete votes in one of the many chat rooms (such as the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)).