# Can we add a auto-comment for "not even a partial answer to the actual question" in the LQRQ?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

The help center in **"Why and how are some answers deleted?"** article says:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
>   This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers*
> - asking another, different question*
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses*
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site*
> - **not even a partial answer to the actual question**

Now, of these, 1, 2, 3 and 5 are addressed by the comment templates of the review queue, 4 is more of an special case, but 6 can be accurately acted upon by reviewers, yet they seems to [pick random reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/792066) that doesn't quite catch the issue with the answer.

The text can be something like:

> This answers doesn't address any of the problems presented on the question. It may be posted by mistake on another question or changes in the question invalidated this answer. Check the question and edit your answer accordingly or delete your answer.

I know it may be crude, but... think about the children!

Comment: Is this the Orange case?

Comment: What scenarios has this been identified as ambiguous, and why do you feel that this will address the ambiguity?

Comment: @rene I think... yes

Comment: @Makoto there have been several discussions, [very sour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/792066), when the flaggers/reviewers read the answer in the context of the question and feel that it doesn't address the issues presented in the question and try to get it deleted, as the help center recommends. This normally ends up on the moderator declining the flag or a [fight between reviewers in the LQRQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/792066)

Comment: I'm still trying to noodle this.  Deletion in general is reserved for stuff that needs to be removed from the site lest it actively causes harm.  An answer that's just crap should be downvoted.  Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Can we instead make a big reminder in the review bar saying that the question doesn't actually matter and that the answer only has to be a valid attempted answer? Possibly with links to [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563), [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/4639281)

Comment: @Makoto well, if you post a question about how to sum two numbers in python, and someone answers how to obtain the product of 3 numbers in Java, wouldn't you want to delete this answer?

Comment: @Braiam That would be a wrong answer, but still an answer. That would qualify for downvotes and delete votes from users with 20k+ reputation, but not for flags or recommending deletion in the LQPRQ.

Comment: @TinyGiant is not even wrong. Is totally misplaced!

Comment: @Braiam No, it is wrong. A wrong answer is an answer that doesn't correctly answer the question.

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense.  In that regard, it's not that I disagree, but perhaps the system needs to do a better job to clean those things up.  The thing is we have a very limited number of delete votes, and while I've got ink on my hands from deleting utter crap answers, the system really needs to step in and handle this.

Comment: @Makoto exactly my point. If you share the load with 2kers reviewers that would be awesome, no? ;)

Comment: @Makoto or provide delete votes to more users, like 10k rep users.

Comment: @Braiam I think that lowering the bar from 20k to 2k is a pretty big leap.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  If you force the system to delete answers that have been massively downvoted, then the number of delete votes that we really need stays at about 30 (at 35k+).

Comment: @TinyGiant well, the slackers have to do something, no?

Comment: Well, that is a good idea. So, if an answer reaches a score of -10, automatically delete it? @Makoto

Comment: I can throw together a query later today after work to see how many answers would be impacted, and if we'd be losing anything of substantial value.  Life would get complicated with accepted answers and self-answers and self-accepted answers...but I still think it's a viable option.  I'm not sure if there's a threshold of score besides the same one we use for questions, but I can run some tests.

Comment: I'd say that it would be easy enough to just exclude accepted answers from that rule. @Makoto

Comment: @TinyGiant:  No.  If an accepted answer is downvoted to oblivion, that should count as well.

Comment: @Makoto how would that manage answers that solve the issue presented on the question, but otherwise introduce adverse effects, like security holes, performance degradation, etc.?

Comment: @Braiam: Well that's just the thing.  I don't know how that would look.  Although I would suspect an answer score of -4 or lower to be one that is just patently wrong or harmful, so I'm not entirely sure if we should be worried about that.  Yes, people vote arbitrarily and they will upvote an answer that introduces an SQL vulnerability if they felt like it, but the hope (and general tendency of the community) is to downvote terrible answers.  As I said, after work I'll write a few queries to explore those possibilities.  I think it could work.

Comment: @Makoto Mind you though, that would mean that a ring of 10 people would have infinite power to delete recently posted answers in seconds. Because once an answer gets deleted, the DV you spent on it gets free'd aswell. That would create a pretty massive potential for abuse by people with as low as 125 reputation. Essentially 10 people banding together in a chat or voting ring could unilaterally delete new answers to any questions if they get to them before UVs had a chance to come in (and even then)

Comment: @Makoto adding to Magisch comment, reviewers are auditable, voters no. Is more easy to detect and correct a problem with reviewers, since their presence is public rather than voters that are anonymous by default.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Note that there's [a lot of disagreement](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270) about whether even the current behavior of not showing questions to diamond mods is desirable; many, including myself, would far rather change the UI in the other direction to make it reliable to delete ridiculous misplaced answers no matter who reviews or votes on it. A change that encourages leaving absolute garbage around for someone else to pick up instead of handling it in the queue for garbage is not one I can support.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I completely disagree with that sentiment as it would impose a minimum requirement of subject matter knowledge to be able to process the flags. What about low traffic or otherwise obscure tags? That is adding far too much subjectivity to something that is currently objective and reviewable by all. I fear that adding the subject matter knowledge requirement will just raise wait times for flags, increase improper handling of flags, and inflate the size of the flag queue. I like it the way it is, I just wish more reviewers reviewed properly.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Requiring mods to occasionally skip is no very bad thing; if no diamond has the necessary skill to pick out whether it is or isn't an answer, that's fine, but the current absurd outcomes ("no this Python answer to a VB.NET question should not be deleted with NAA") are not something I am going to remain content with. Mods are elected on the basis of discretion in following the rules, not slavish adherence to simplistic guidelines. Reviewing "properly" should never include allowing known patterns of terrible garbage posts to remain systemically.

Comment: @NathanTuggy just a note: a mod can view the answer directly from the queue, with a single click, [check Gilles comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag/286270#comment156539_286270)

Comment: @NathanTuggy that energy would be most usefully applied to getting users with delete votes to use them. Bastardizing a working system which is only supposed to handle situations where the community cannot handle the post into something that will be intended to delete all wrong answers because the community isn't using the powers available to them is not logical. I would like to know 1) how many users will flag something without down voting, and 2) how many users that have delete votes do not cast them when flagging these answers.

Comment: People are using the flagging system and review queues as a shortcut,  which is not helpful in any way, nor what the systems are designed for. Correct the voting and flagging practices instead of breaking the system. At any given point in time, someone with 15 rep can get up to 100 flags in a day. Do we really want to treat those 100 flags from 15 rep users like delete votes?

Comment: @TinyGiant 1 flag + 6 2k users or 3 20k users

Comment: Because [reviewers in the LQPRQ have proven that they make informed decisions, right?](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/7-28-2014/AnSME7.gif)

Comment: @TinyGiant I trust reviewers more than moderators to delete stuff I want deleted, also, 20kers may pitch in in any moment too.

Comment: Well of course you do, reviewers in the LQPRQ delete everything they see without question, while moderators actually review the posts.

Comment: @TinyGiant [unlike moderators, they read answers in context](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag/286270#comment156539_286270), and that's what I do too.

Comment: From what I've seen, most reviewers don't read much of anything in the LQPRQ. We don't elect reviewers. Also when users actually cast delete votes on answers their name is attached to it. If a post is deleted from review without any comments linking to the review, you would have to request that information from a moderator to be able to find out.

Comment: @TinyGiant [you sure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568)

Comment: Well, I didn't know about that, but your name still isn't attached prominently to the deleted post like it would be if you voted to delete it. But whatever, if you want to abuse the flagging system as a substitute for delete votes, there's nothing stopping you. It just sucks when reviewers who review correctly fail audits because six 2k rep users recommended deletion of a valid answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant still, it is auditable. I'm not even sure how is this conversation even on topic for my proposal.