# Can we upgrade the Roomba to automatically delete poorly received answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, automatic-deletion

Spurred on by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316181/1079354) and [subsequent discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316181/can-we-add-a-auto-comment-for-not-even-a-partial-answer-to-the-actual-question#comment303101_316181), I decided to do a bit of research into what would happen if we let the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) loose on poorly received *answers*.

The results are interesting, to say the least.

[Negatively scored answers on Stack Overflow - aggregation by last edit date](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432404/negatively-scored-answers-on-stack-overflow-aggregation-by-last-edit-date)

The rule being followed for now:  the answer has been edited in the last X days, where X is 30, 60, 90, 180, or 365 days.  I can edit the query to incorporate other rules if we want to see that.

The main thing to call out is that I doubt we'd be losing any substantial answers with a move like this.  Notice that after a year of no edits and a score of -3 or below, there are *lots* of answers (roughly 33K) that could be culled because they could be really poor.

Of course, this doesn't take into account the fact that the question may be on a low-traffic tag or that the question itself was particularly heinous (although that's even *more* impetus to make the question and answer pair go away), but it does offer something.

I'm interested in something like this since it seems that there's a bit of tension as to when we should use our delete votes, and whether or not using them on posts that really don't answer the question (but are attempts at an answer, as is a very heated topic in these parts) is a valid action.  My gut tells me that the system should be able to cull crappy answers from the site instead of relying on a gang of 20K+ users who have a ton of free time on their hands.

I've also put together a follow-up query to answer some other questions:

- What about accepted answers?
- What about a breakout between upvotes and downvotes?

That query is here:

[Negatively scored answers on Stack Overflow - upvote, downvote, and acceptance breakouts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432463/negatively-scored-answers-on-stack-overflow-upvote-downvote-and-acceptance-br)

Determining if an answer is "tightly" scored is entirely too tedious to do, and the key point we want to discover is the average between the upvotes and downvotes across all answers scored at a specific value.  I've provided that, and the trend is what I'd expect:  as the score total gets lower, the likelihood of the answer being upvoted increases, which may not have any ultimate bearing on its quality at all.

Also, the breakout on accepted answers indicates to me that the most likely scenario you'll see an answer with a negative score that's accepted is one that has a score of **-1**.  The likelihood of occurrence is practically cut in half with any other scores.  That said, the fact that an answer *may* be accepted doesn't factor in a lot, but I'm not sure that the script should be allowed to delete an answer that's accepted without really considering more edge cases.

Thoughts?  Concerns?  Issues with the query?

Comment: Would it be possible to see the break down between up/down? A score of -3 is very different if it's +0/-3 vs +44/-47.

Comment: @Andy:  I can work on that a bit later.  That would be interesting to see.

Comment: Based on those stats, I think that if an has existed for one week and has a score of less than or equal to -5, or has existed for one month and has a score of less than or equal to -3, it should be deleted. This should happen regardless of activity on or status of the answer. This would also help the roomba clean up off-topic question that are answered prior to being closed.

Comment: Count upvotes as 2 points and downvotes as -1 and if the score after adding weights is -3, then you can automatically delete imho.  The 2/3rds consensus needs to be that it is a bad answer, not just half.

Comment: Showing how *not* to solve a problem, especially when juxtaposed against a correct solution, has value.  Bonus points if it is cargo cult.  Most visible when just about everybody gets their underwear in a bundle because a poster deletes his answer and scrubs its content.  Legitimizing a bot to do what a post owner is not allowed to do is the most obvious problem with this proposal.

Comment: What is there to say that a user is not allowed delete their own downvoted answer and scrub the content? @Hans

Comment: @TinyGiant For one, if it's accepted. I remember a very high rep user last year who just made an honest mistake on a regex question in the Python tag, OP marked their answer as accepted, it got downvoted to like -15 and they couldn't delete it for a month until the OP came back. Not that I had a problem with it being deleted, it was just a bit amusing.

Comment: So we want to keep bad answers around... because they are amusing? @Donkey

Comment: @TinyGiant No. You asked what there is to say a user cannot delete their own downvoted answer. I'm saying that answer being accepted is a case. Hence why I mentioned "_not that I had a problem with it being deleted_".

Comment: @HansPassant:  The only thing I'm aware of that a post owner *can't* do with their post after it's been voted on is delete it if and only if it's accepted.  I'm putting another query together which *includes* accepted answers, and it doesn't make up a very large amount of answers, either, so I'm not entirely sure how that would apply.  You may have a legitimate concern, but could you voice it as an answer instead so I could properly dissect and evaluate it?

Comment: @Donkey Ok, I was confused as to your premise by the rest of your comment.

Comment: @Andy:  It's late here and doing that kind of breakout is tricky, so I've provided an average instead.  I'll try to get something a bit more accurate at a later time.

Comment: There is another big advantage to consistently cleaning up a lot of those loose ends: More people will downvote where appropriate, as they are more likely to recoup their investment in the short- to mid-term.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  That's where I'm going with this. I want the downvote feature to have a bit more bite when it comes to getting rid of answers, as I didn't have anything that would've made that clear.

Comment: The flip side of that is we'd essentially be giving low-rep users 30 *untraceable delete votes* per day, @Deduplicator. Right now deletion (whether via review or via vote) is pretty traceable; you can see who is voting or reviewing and access to both is tightly controlled. Downvotes are anonymous, readily available, and should probably stay that way.

Comment: Low rep?  I thought only 20K+ users could delete answers right now @Shog9.

Comment: Yup, but it only takes 125 rep to *downvote* @Makoto.

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, fair point.  However, what I'm trying to suss out with this is really both whether or not it's viable, and how long we should wait until it could happen.  The only metric I'm looking at is time; are there any other metrics that would potentially sway your decision such as "last time answer was upvoted"?

Comment: There are a lot of other criteria we could throw into this, @Makoto... But how many are actually a strong signal? Even the current *question* roomba inspired some fairly negative behaviors (gang-downvoting of positively-scored answers to spark the deletion of the question) - I suspect this would make that even worse. Consider compiling a list of answers you feel should be removed and trying to extract commonalities from them - then we can test to see how many false-positives crop up.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the solution to this whole thing would be to make delete votes for both questions and answers drastically lower in rep required. The entire debate comes down to controlling the torrent of sewage that is new questions and not giving individuals too much power. I think we're erring on the safe side currently, which is good, but still erring.

Comment: @Shog9:  I'll do that a bit after work and see what I result in.

Comment: Why, @Magisch? Is there really so much that isn't being deleted right now? Very few people with delete votes even use them. We're erring on the side of not giving people who haven't written much the ability to remove others' writing willy-nilly... I tend to think this makes sense.

Comment: @Shog9 Thats because almost nobody has them. 10k is a big mark to get. I'd use all of them every day just like I do close votes if I had them. The problem is not that not enough people are able to delete/close, its that you guys heavily rate limit those who do have them and deter alot of people who enjoy moderation

Comment: @Shog9 The current system would essentially force me to farm rep for a few more months to even get to delete votes.

Comment: @Shog9 I think its time for SO to start to let the people who really want to moderate moderate a good bit more. Currently so many bad questions get through, not because they lack attention, but because the few people who care ran out of DVs/Delete votes/ close votes.

Comment: Whether or not you "farm rep" is your own choice, @Magisch. But you haven't put even 200 answers onto the site yet; barely 100 that've been upvoted. Heck, if you wanted more downvoted answers to be deleted, you could start with your own - and yet you're lamenting the lack of power over others' instead? Invest more of your own work into the system before you gripe that your share of ownership is too small.

Comment: @Magisch "not because they lack attention, but because the few people who care ran out of DVs/Delete votes/ close votes" Do you have anything to back that up that's not just anecdotal?

Comment: @Shog9 answers for me are more of a means to an end. If you checked, you probably saw my answers are mostly for easy c questions. Thats because im not a professional coder yet (im an apprentice). My enjoyment of this site comes mainly from keeping it clean.

Comment: I guess a way to incentivise people to keep the site clean would be to start awarding small rep bounties for undisputed / "known good" moderation actions that people do.

Comment: Trivia: the roughly 8800 users with 10K on Stack Overflow have cast roughly 31000 delete votes in the past 30 days. That's not quite 4 delete votes a month, and includes deletions of their own posts. You start out with 5 delete votes per *day* at 10K, and can earn as many as 30... There exists a tremendous potential here that isn't being used... Perhaps start by asking the folks who *can* delete why they aren't deleting the stuff you think should be gone @Magisch?

Comment: @Shog9 Could be that some people who really enjoy answering questions don't enjoy moderating so much, and vice versa. Could also be because moderation is currently its own reward only (save a few badges) and answering comes with a shiny incrementing number.

Comment: As for focusing on cleanup rather than contribution... Ever try to sweep a dirt floor clean? You have to know when to stop sweeping and put something down over it, or you'll just sweep your way into oblivion.

Comment: @Shog9 fair point, but I believe there is currently an imbalance tilted towards not enough moderation on So, not too much.

Comment: You can believe whatever you want, but you might wanna start by earning the privilege to see deleted posts, to view the tools that list recently-deleted stuff, close stats, etc. Make informed observations, y'know. Anyway, this is probably quite distracting to Makoto, so if you wish to continue this conversation join me in [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: @Shog9 Thats for me still a good few months of churning out apprentice-grade answers to easy questions away.

Comment: @Shog9 I realize that it was probably not your intention, but your comment about the dirt floors just gave me the impression that you think all of us downvoters, close voters, and delete voters should just give up, because we're just cleaning some crap off of the pile of crap, and it doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: You *can* sweep a dirt floor, @Tiny. You just stop when you hit packed dirt. Next time I'll choose a more familiar analogy.

Comment: @Andy - `44/47` does not prove any relative value any more than `0/3`. Most likely just shows that there are `44` incompetent people that think the answer is correct when it isn't or is harmful or whatever.

Comment: @Shog9 - have been down this rabbithole trying to get discussion on why high rep people do not cast downvotes EVER, much less DELETE votes. It is a waste of time. The # of people that can vs do is not going to change unless you can receive rep from casting downvotes some how.

Comment: @Shog9: _"start by asking the folks who can delete why they aren't deleting the stuff"_ -- you're making some excellent points in the comments, but I do want to respond to this specific one: I can't speak for everyone, naturally, but for my own part I do vote to delete when I can and it's appropriate. The problem is, voting to delete a post isn't even available right away, when the moderation tasks are front-and-center. I occasionally go back and skim through my recent close votes to look for eligible deletions, but doing so is a pain and so doesn't happen often.

Comment: @Shog9: I guess I'm saying, I agree that the feature requested here doesn't need implementing. But I do think it might be worth thinking about how we might improve the work-flow for manual delete-voting. Answers don't even have the mechanism of having close votes to review, and that mechanism isn't that helpful in the first place.

Comment: @Magisch: _"Thats because almost nobody has them. 10k is a big mark to get."_ Well, hey, sure, if 8,863 people is "almost nobody". I'm not convinced you'd want them all around your house for drinks at the same time though.

Comment: @PreferenceBean 8k people of how many accounts?

Comment: @Magisch: Does it matter? That's almost nine thousand people with the ability to delete terrible answers and, as far as I can see, they're doing that job just fine.

Comment: @PreferenceBean *Lightness* Stopped racing in the *orbit*?

Comment: @BhargavRao: Just making a little stop at the ISS for some maintenance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I made a [userscript](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/VotesPageEnhancements.user.js) (requires tampermoney or greasemonkey depending on your browser) that helps with that. It loads the full post in it's natural form on the votes pages, with all controls working. I use this to do the same thing, go back and find questions to cast my delete votes on, but also to find questions that I've voted to close and see if they are still worthy of closure or not. It works for the all of the votes pages, so you can review your downvotes for answers to delete.

Comment: You're asking whether we should do X. What I'm missing here is **why** we should do X. What's the benefit? What harm do negative-scoring answers cause?

Answer (score 58):

I salute the idea. One possible concern is that it would kill **"involuntary cautionary tale" answers**, i.e. answers that present a prima facie plausible solution that would seem obvious to many, but which, upon closer inspection by other users, is highly inadvisable. Such answers typically end up heavily downvoted, often with a trail of cautionary comments. They then serve as a useful warning sign of what NOT to do. Vacuuming them could remove this useful information.

Typically there will also be a great answer that shows the right way to do it. But it's arguably useful to also point out the wrong way. Sure, you can see the good answer, but you might think, "No, I know, there's an easier way!" And then proceed to implement the bad solution you just came up with, unaware that there are reasons not to do this (and that you're not the first one to come up with this bad solution).

I'm posting this because this happened to me, and I was glad that someone else's mistake was pointed out and dissected, so that I wouldn't attempt to repeat it. I wish I had kept the bookmark. (Had I done so, I would have posted it here: [Request for good examples of heavily downvoted answers that are worth keeping on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316271/119775))

---

Addendum: Some have argued that such answers shouldn't be left lying around, but rather rewritten as direct "don't do this because XYZ" answers, or merged into other, better answers, such that the valuable information they contain is better presented. That's a point worth discussing, but it is orthogonal to the question being discussed here i.e. it doesn't depend on auto-deletion. Also note that once the original answer is auto-deleted, it's harder to do those things; and in the meantime most users can't see the cautionary remarks.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?  I can't imagine an answer that has a cautionary tale which has been *downvoted* in the extreme...

Comment: What is the point in showing someone what not to do when there are lots of information (*in most of the cases*) on what is best to do...?

Comment: I can't think of a heavily downvoted answer (with no voting irregularities) that would be worth keeping on this site tbh.

Comment: @TJ: Because sometimes you can see the suggestion of what to do, but think, "No, I know, there's an easier way!" And then proceed to implement the bad solution you just came up with, unaware that there are reasons not to do this (because that involuntary cautionary tale answer got deleted).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You know, I end up searching for something in stackoverflow when I have no such thing as "an easier way" in my mind. If I had one, I already screwed up with that and that is why I'm here looking for better answers, not worse ones.  I come here  trying to solve the problem with what I thought was the easier way. I already have a problem. You seem to be targeting those who never try anything but starts their job copy pasting from stackoverflow..? Do we really need to keep crap in favor of them..?

Comment: @Makoto: I've seen this every now and then, but I haven't bookmarked any, no. Also, I clarified what I meant by "cautionary tale answer". I don't mean an answer that says: "Here's an apparent solution, but don't do this, it's dangerous." I mean an answer that says: "Here's a solution, do this!" with many comments that then say "No! Don't do that! Because XYZ."

Comment: @TJ: I'm not talking about "crap". I'm talking about seemingly plausible solutions, with subsequent valuable warnings / information why not to use them. I'm not targeting silly users; I'm targeting people like my past self.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I don't really know what *"seemingly plausible solutions, with subsequent valuable warnings / information why not to use them"* means. My understanding of it is: The thing that you shouldn't do. As per my understanding, a developer visits a question for 2 reasons: 1) he has no clue how to go about doing something. Solution: We show him the right way to do it. 2) He screwed up with what seemed plausible solutions Solution: We show him the right way to do it. The key thing to note is: If I have a seemingly solution thingy... In most cases I give it a try first.

Comment: I can't think of a situation when I google like "Will there be any issues if I try X" (my seemingly plausible solution). In case if I do, and if there is a question and an answer for that in stackoverflow - The answer to that will be a good positive answer explaining the issues with my approach and alternative solutions. How come a horribly downvoted answer is going to help me there..? If it was good for something, it wouldn't be in that state

Comment: So you, @TJ, have never needed this personally. Good for you. I'm just posting this because something like this has helped me in the past, and I'm assuming I'm not the only one. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett This isn't about you or me, This is my last attempt at making you understand why what you're saying doesn't make sense to me.  Scenario 1) Someone is looking for the best way to do "X". We show him solutions that are highly accepted by the community, everyone is happy. Scenario 2) someone is having an issue with x, or not sure whether his approach "x" is best, in which case he searches "is 'x'the best way to do 'y'". The point is, the solution that explains why x is not a good way to do y is going to have a good feedback from the community.

Comment: This is probably why Magisch said he can't think of such a downvoted answer. If it is downvoted it's most probably posted in the wrong place (as an answer to "what is the best way to do x"). There is no point in presenting the crappy ways to someone who's looking for the best way.

Comment: This is the classic use case, but I have to admit... leaving "never ever do this" to the subtleties of -10 score with, of all things, *explanatory comments* lingering around seems a little bit silly. It's worth considering writing the cautionary tale up *as such* in one or more of the other answers. Whether the downvoted answer should be auto-deleted, deleted routinely by humans, or what, I'm not sure... but given that we currently incentivize self-deletion, it seems like deleting more is consonant with that.

Comment: @TJ The number of "use volatile here this will totally work!" answers on most C++ questions about concurrency that luckily get downvoted do probably help at least a bit (actually concurrency is really the only topic where I'd think this actually happens, because it is complicated and "seems to work")

Comment: This is a great point. When starting a project with a new technology, I often follow "related question" trails to get a deeper understanding of what I'm likely to mess up.

Comment: Every time I saw an incorrect answer (no need to invent new terms), its gist could be non-taxingly incorporated into the correct one like "way X is flawed: Y". And I never saw heavily downvoted answers at all - probably because [they are more likely to be deleted as VLQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Comment: This is indeed a great point. Wider context is always important. Why is everybody so insistent on nuking content to oblivion? Why must everything inevitably be _deleted_ nowadays? Gosh.

Answer (score 50):

Automatic deletion for questions works because there are multiple signals that can be used to determine abandoned questions... One of the best being the presence of *answers*. If no one could find a way to provide a helpful answer to a question, then there's a really good bet it isn't a useful question; votes (down or close) help to reinforce that.

Answers don't have that. Answers *are* much easier to get rid of without automation though - votes from high-rep users and flags from everyone both lead to speedy deletion in cases where that's appropriate.

I think leaving answer deletion in the hands of actual humans is a good idea.

Comment: This still leaves two open questions:  how can an answer be considered helpful if it's been downvoted, and what does this imply for the deletion privilege - that we're *really* meant to be using our delete powers not just for dangerous content, but also low quality content?

Comment: Is there ever a case where an answer can be considered useful if it is heavily downvoted?

Comment: @Makoto on sites where I have 20k (only AU) I vtd lossy answers to lossy questions all the time, mainly to allow roomba do its job.

Comment: Yes, @Tiny. I think [Jean sums up this scenario well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316208/can-we-upgrade-the-roomba-to-automatically-delete-poorly-received-answers/316214#316214)

Comment: Well, while that is an interesting sentiment, I haven't actually seen an example that is worth keeping around. If anything the answers usually end us as "Don't do it this way:", in which case they are usually upvoted to draw attention to something you shouldn't do. I would love to see actual examples of heavily downvoted content that is worth keeping on the site, which couldn't possibly exist in the form of "Don't do it this way".

Comment: Well, post a discussion asking for it then @Tiny. I mean, if you think this is a good idea, then do your research first. I'm sure I'm not the only one who has come across usefully-wrong answers before, but I don't exactly keep a list of them - so put up a request & let folks help you as they're able.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm going to take a guess that some of the downvoted posts that might need to stick around would be obsolete answers as technology evolved.  They might have been correct at one point, but now they maybe be wrong for new tech.  These need to stick around for people stuck with older technology.

Comment: @Shog9 [Like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316271/4639281)?

Comment: @bluefeet I agree that there are downvoted answers that are useful as "what to avoid" examples. However, I've not found the community to generally downvote obsolete answers, especially if someone edits them with version information. I'm not saying downvotes on obsolete answers don't happen but I don't recall ever running into an answer that got into the negative *merely* because it had been made obsolete. Ironically, I do have an answer that was downvoted for being obsolete. The downvoter commented with his reason and made it clear that the downvote was his. I just don't think it is common.

Comment: @bluefeet That sounds like it should be it's own answer, as it is a different situation than the one Jean pointed out, to which Shog was referring. Again, I would love actual. examples

Comment: @Louis It's probably not common, but it does happen. I did a lot of research into "obsolete"/negatively scored answers for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot). The problem is, it can be very difficult to identify these by querying the DB.  I've looked at voting history - more DV's than UpV's over the 2nd half of the life of the answer, etc. It's tough to find them, but they exist.

Comment: @bluefeet Er... I know they exist. As I said, I do have one answer that was downvoted for being obsolete. It still has a positive score though.

Comment: @TinyGiant [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35201541/1906307) is a good example of a mistake that people would be likely to make. However, it so happens that the upvoted answer on that question does mention the very issue that the bad answer runs into so the answer does not need to stay. Ideally, it seems to me that's what should happen: if someone posts a bad solution illustrating a mistake people are likely to make, then an answer that presents a good solution should also explain why the bad answer is bad.

Comment: @Louis could you post that [over here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316271/4639281)?

Comment: That's an interesting example, @Louis, because until recently there was *another* answer to that question which described the same technique and in fact it was this answer which motivated the *correct* answer... IOW, it's possible that the removal of the previous (incorrect) answer resulted in the posting of a new one. This is exactly the sort of answer I'd like to see remain as a warning to folks that their "clever solution" is neither novel nor a good idea.

Answer (score 26):

I, like [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316266/426671), don't think this is a good idea.  It's possible that negatively-scored answers are helpful to users.

I looked extensively at [obsolete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers) answers and [negatively scored accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot) to see if there was something that could be improved in how we handle them.  Many of these negatively scored answers, may have been great once when the technology was brand new (5+ years ago). But now, the technology has evolved and the answer isn't good for the current tech, so it gets downvoted.  These answers exist on the site and are helpful to those stuck using old tech.

Answers specific to [sql-server-2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2000) aren't wrong for those stuck still using it, but the answer isn't very helpful to someone using [sql-server-2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012). We don't want to delete an answer that might be negatively scored because **it's possible someone still needs it.**

I'd prefer leaving this to users to vote to delete, so there is some sanity check on the answer before leaving it to a bot to delete based on score.

Comment: I'm fine with this sentiment, but I feel that there may be things that we could do to suss out and identify answers based in old tech and answers which are completely terrible.  Right now it does feel like there's no clear answer on if a 20K user should spend their delete votes on answers which are terrible in addition to deleting content which is harmful.

Comment: @Makoto I've tried/am still trying to figure out ways to identify them.  I've got some ideas but nothing has come to fruition yet... I am still looking and trying to get buy-in from others.

Comment: Well, there's lots of discussion and feature-requests around ways to mark outdated answers as outdated / best prior version x.y . Current options: Downvoting (likely ineffective due to inertia, and actively harmful if old version still in use), editing (probably rejected as against authors intent, whether it updated the post to the new best or just added a warning about applicable versions), writing a new answer (see inertia), closing the old question as a dupe of a new one to get rid of the old answers (*very* shady, and reversed fast), and of course the classic one, despair. Any others?

Comment: @Deduplicator Lots of things I've contemplated and tested internally during the months that I've looked at this problem.  Why do you think my feet turned blue?

Comment: I also have an answer, a right answer of course! :), which has +7,-9. I like to watch the fight between good and evil over the years... At the moment evil leads by -2

Answer (score 11):

It's not clear to me that this is a problem in need of a solution.

We already (by default) sort answers by vote/acceptance. So if a highly negatively voted answer exists alongside positive answers, most people won't even see it.

Using the Roomba to delete old and worthless questions makes sense, because questions represent search targets, particularly from off-site. Using the Roomba to delete answers doesn't seem to have the same effect. It can affect in-site searches, as they do search through answers. But a highly downvoted answer doesn't appear high up in an in-site search very often anyway.

Culling old questions is helpful to the site. I don't see how culling bad answers is helpful.

Comment: Answers are search targets, too.  I don't disagree that answers can fall out of favor due to their age, but what of patently incorrect answers?  Should we really have to see them on the answer page?  What of users with sufficient rep like yourself and myself - should we be culling them since we have that power?  These are the things that this sort of feature is trying to suss out.

Comment: @Makoto: "*Should we really have to see them on the answer page?*" Don't scroll down that far. "*should we be culling them since we have that power?*" If you have reviewed the answer and decided that it should go, then do so. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score -1):

There's a beef I have with this... It is that there's no way to audit these deletions. No way to redeem yourself or to inform the user what he could do to improve their answer. I don't think an automatic process can determine if an answer can be accurately and silently deleted. There should be some friction to get this done in a sane way.

Comment: Note that I never specified a specific time or score cut-off - I was more or less looking in the "months to years" category to avoid scenarios that you describe.

Comment: This objection applies to everything the roomba does. What makes this proposal different?

Comment: @JoshCaswell err... no. See Shog's answer. Roomba uses many indicators, in this case it would be just score + age.

Comment: I can always add *more* indicators.  The first one was a rough indicator to gauge reaction and perception.  I can clearly see that age alone is a bad choice.

Comment: _Shog's_ objection is specific to this proposal; _your_ objection applies to everything the roomba does. There's no explicit audits of roomba question deletion; there's no way to "redeem" or "inform" for those deletions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell no. I don't have issues with what roomba does. It does what it does for a good reason: [questions without answers or any indicator that someone cares are frustrating](https://xkcd.com/979/). If you see a question without upvotes nor answer for more than a year, people that arrive there because they have the same problem (or, the question is just misrepresented) will run into a brick wall. Deleting the question on those cases so it gets re-asked, with all that entails (looks fresh, it targets more eyes, etc.) is good. Deleting an answer because it isn't hot anymore isn't.

Comment: You should edit the material from your comment into your answer, then.