# Why was my "too chatty" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Today I flagged a comment where the user asking the question basically stated "I'm a beginner at the language and am lost" as "too chatty". Had the same sentence been put in the question I'd have removed it as [fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/1630171), because it doesn't add anything substantial.

However, the flag was declined almost immediately. Why is that?

It's just one comment, so I don't think a custom flag would be warranted.

I can provide a link to the question in question if required, but would prefer to avoid invoking the meta-effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it was fairly new, marked as "too chatty" and it's not always feasible to check entire comment threads (we only see the comment flagged - not the context) - it looked like it could be part of a response to something the OP didn't understand which may well have provided context in previous/on-going/further comments.

I've looked at the context, and that obviously isn't the case, so I've deleted the comment now - sorry about that.

Comment: And why is it not feasible to check the entire comment thread? What's reducing a feasibility?

Comment: @lux something related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag#comment156539_286270)