# Decline..Decline everywhere

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

Today while checking the most comments, I came to this post:

[Is the C standard library embedded with STM32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709666/is-the-c-standard-library-embedded-with-stm32)

Now the post was [on hold] and the comments really are all chatty.

Someone telling OP to read the documentation instead of asking a question, and also arguing with another person, which in the long run is not going to benefit anyone if they were able to see this question, since this might be deleted one month later by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Now I flagged them all as no longer needed, and to my surprise all the flags were declined.

Now my question is:

Why did they get declined, aren't those comments too chatty? Do you think these comments will help anyone later on?

Comment: Some of them are indeed chatty.

Comment: Protip: when there are too many comments to be flagged, use *one* custom flag instead to request for comment clean-up.

Comment: *Do you think these comments will help anyone later on?* that is maybe not the greatest reason to keep a comment. Asking yourself if the comments help to improve the post and/or indicate issues with the post is a better rule of thumb. Even with this rule applied the comments in your example some still meet the criteria for no longer needed.

Comment: Most of the comments were relevant to the question, the one not needed was marked as helpful and the comment was deleted.  I agree with @AndrewT. perhaps save yourself some time and make one comment flag asking for a thread clean up. It's good you bothered to go to the trouble and review the comments, don't let this dishearten you

Comment: actually nothing was removed.. all the flags were declined..

Comment: @PeterHaddad there is a flagged comment that was removed - not your flag though. :/

Comment: The [c] tag has a big, big comment moderation problem.  Too many contributors feel compelled to explain why they don't know the answer and why it is not their problem.  There have been multiple attempts to address this in the past, but they didn't last and moderators just gave up on it.  Little point in pursuing a job that is never done.  Luckily the question was asked before, I posted a link to it.  If you upvote the comment then somebody might be able to see it.

Comment: As the one who wrote (at least some of) those comments: Comments are to be read in the context of the original post. With all due respect, but the word of embedded development is quite different from the PC/server world. You do have to know what you are doing and there are a lot more things involved for embedded development than we could answer here. The question you reference and the foolow up comments by OP showed clearly a short and straight question wold raise a rat's tail of follow-up questions. So, as a shortcut, I pointed OP at reading the documentation, which is vital anyway …

Comment: … the following comments showed my assumption was correct. I left that thread after some back and forth as I didn't see the will to look into my recommendations. The rest was the unfortunately not rare discussion with a regular pulling red herrings for beginners (I don't imply intention). It's as it is, some things need a good fundation before one should start them. You wouldn't build a skyscraper without knowing about the forces, weather, earthquake conditions, etc. - would you? To be clear: I don't blame anyone for not knowing about a subject.

Comment: … I'm for teaching fishing, not feeding a fish. Searching and reading the documentation would have gained the knowledge about the subject massively (assuming they were understood - rinse and repeat) and given a lot of very useful context, too. Finally: I was aware the question would go `/dev/null`, so I couldn't see harm replying to OPs comments. I'd been fine, too if they were moved to chat. But then: _shrug_ what would that change, but leave OP without the infos.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not attacking you or anything like that.. I know it is better to read the docs and then ask a question... The only reason I asked because I was wondering why did the comments get declined if the question is gonna be deleted anyway.. but I got the answer to that below

Comment: @PeterHaddad: Anyway, I think sharing my view would be helpful. In addition: 1) I'm not a native speaker, and I tend to be (a bit) verbose writing English. 2) The comments **are helpful**. OP **has to** read the documentation eventually. Maybe not for the first "Hello World", but for any useful firmware. You don't have a padded net on bare-metal. It's a different world. Maybe I should have stopped after OPs "read what" comment, but I still was hoping … (I'm indifferent about the other thread at that question, though)

Comment: Again, i'm with OP always reading the documentations first.. I'm not against that at all..as I said I only asked the question to know the reasons for all those declined comments and that's it.. you are kinda taking it personal for some reason..

Comment: @PeterHaddad: I'm no way taking it personal. I'm fine if you think I should delete my reasoning above. Just ping me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I *dismissed* the 26 comment flags, and you *already* cited my reasoning:

> which in the long run is not going to benefit anyone if they were able to see this question, since this might be deleted one month later by Community.

The post is not going to be around in a while, there is no point in flagging umpteen comments, creating work for moderators where the system is going to clean all this up automatically.

I skimmed through the first few comments in the flag queue, then opened the post itself because it wasn't clear those first few were off topic. The first one read:

> It is not clear what you are asking. Show your own research, what does the documentation say and your C book? Typically bar-metal is a freestanding implementation with only the mandatory headers provided by the compiler. gcc particularily never includes the standard libary, neither on Windows, nor Linux, MacOS, etc. Read the reference manual of the STM32. There is nothing in the Flash and the bootloader is just that.

That's not too chatty, that's giving clear feedback as to why the post is off topic. The following comments also seemed relevant. But since the post was already closed, I knew it was not going to last, and dismissed all the flags (our only option, I can't respond to explain why). It really wasn't going to be worth having to read through a *huge* comment thread here.

Dismissed flags do not count towards a flag ban, they don't affect your ability to flag in future.

Even if that wasn't the case, please flag the post or a single comment with an explanation as to why these need to be removed in future. Know that we can respond to flags on posts, but not on comments, or I'd have told you directly in the flag response why I declined the flags.

Comment: (didnt downvote) but only wondering won't this get me banned from flagging later?

Comment: "*The post is not going to be around in a while*" - Why this assumption? What if OP actually edited his question and made it relevant?

Comment: @Maroun: so **flag the comments _then_**.

Comment: @Maroun: the majority of low-quality posts by 1-rep users never get edited into shape. This specific post is too far off into off-topic territory, I highly doubt that that magical hypothetical situation will occur there.

Comment: totally agree - the comments are necessary if the OP is going to edit the post and make a half decent question - once the question is edited into shape, they can be deleted. If it's not edited the question will be automatically deleted, and the comments with it

Comment: @PeterHaddad: no, it will not, because comment flags are dismissed, not declined.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Further, getting banned from declined post flags does not ban you from flagging comments.

Comment: If dismissed flags don't count towards a flag ban, which flags *do* count towards a flag ban?

Comment: @Donald: *declined* flags count. Comment flags are always either marked helpful (by a moderatordeleting or editing  the comment), or they are dismissed. So *comment* flags never count towards such bans.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So "dismissed" is for comment flags and "declined" is for post flags?

Comment: Exactly. Not that this is clear in the per-user flag page, where they are labelled as declined. But at least they are tallied separately from flags on posts.

Comment: This is jarring, at the very least. Moderators want to review NAA's without context, but comments flags with context? Why you waste so much time clicking the question and decline *flag by flag*, but can't click a question when it isn't immediately obvious NAA?

Comment: @Braiam who says we don’t view the question when it’s not an obvious NAA flag? And comment flags can’t be handled any other way than one by one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "In all seriousness, like I commented elsewhere, this is why the canned NAA flag is reserved for content that is unequivocally not an attempt to answer any question in a way that makes sense on the site, **no matter the context.**" [BoltClock♦ Feb 18 '15 at 4:28](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question-%e2%86%92#comment156447_286270)

Comment: @Braiam: right, and from that you infer we never look at the context if we feel it’s warranted anyway.

Comment: If you read the next 3 comments, you would notice that that's exactly what a fellow moderator expects the community to expect from them.

Comment: @Braiam: Not sure if you understood this yet, but I'm not in the mood to go over NAA flags yet again with you.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is - these comments are relevant to the question to assist the OP in editing the question to make it on-topic. Once (if) the question has been edited to be on-topic, then these comments are no longer needed.

If the question is not edited, it will be automatically deleted by the system, along with the comments.

It's better to leave the guidance of users there, in the hope that it will be taken.

As mentioned, an easier way is to flag one comment asking for a comment thread clean up.

One thing about this many comments, is it's an indicator the question may be off-topic, as it's requiring so much discussion, in an attempt to clarify it.

Comment: "It's better to leave the guidance of users there, in the hope that it will be taken." -- Yup. The usual boilerplate advice about comments being ephemeral is often given without accounting for short-term value (as opposed to long-term value).

Comment: @duplode perfect point - they're not supposed to be long term resources, but do serve a short term purpose.