# A flag of an obsolete comment got declined, but a prior edit of mine made it obsolete

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

[This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255668/3-d-cartesian-points-to-2-d-hemispherical-and-calculate-the-area-of-2-d-voronoi) was tagged as MATLAB, however not only there is no MATLAB in the body (apart from a vague mention of OP having some functions on the language), but OP edited mentioning that they found a solution and would share it, in R.

OP however did not share the code.

Two comments highlight this

> @Adam Could you please post an answer with your solution, so that you
>   can accept it and the question no longer appears in the 'unanswered'
>   list? Thx – tvo May 4 '16 at 13:51

and

> @AdamErickson This still shows up at the top of the list of unanswered
>   MATLAB questions. Can you please post the answer you say you have
>   found, perhaps a link to the new R package, and accept it as tvo
>   requested as well? – informaton Aug 12 '17 at 16:39

However, as I edited out the MATLAB tag, I decided that this last comment was `obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary`, so I flagged it as such.

But my flag was declined.

Why was it declined? Is this a mistake by mods? Am I being too picky at flagging things and clogging the flag queue? Should I generally ignore this kind of comments?

Comment: The mods don't see your edit of the post I think so they don't connect the dots. If you want a comment removed because you took some action that makes the comment obsolete, use a custom flag and explain what you did and why deleting the comment is the best way forward,

Comment: Both comments ask the OP to post his answer which in my eyes is a valid comment and shouldn't be deleted (untill the answer has been posted)

Comment: @AndréKool but one comment should suffice me thinks?

Comment: @rene Completely true. But does a mod see all the comments or only the one that has been flagged?

Comment: @rene but I doubt the mods knew that the comment was not obsolete before my edit. The only reason that duplicated comment may be considered not unnecessary is because of having the word MATLAB on it, before the edit. Else its clearly unnecessary.

Comment: @yivi I did not flag *both* comments, only the second one.

Comment: @AndréKool IIRC comment flags are shown out of context, so they see the flagged comment and the buttons [approve] [decline]

Comment: @Ander Ok, edit the title as you wish, of course. I was just trying to make it easier to understand, since I found it hardish to parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I declined the comment flag as I couldn't identify why this comment was No Longer Needed:

> @AdamErickson This still shows up at the top of the list of unanswered
>   MATLAB questions. Can you please post the answer you say you have
>   found, perhaps a link to the new R package, and accept it as tvo
>   requested as well? – informaton Aug 12 '17 at 16:39

As only one comment was flagged, I even *loaded the entire question* for the full context and read all the comments on the question.

Both the comments you highlighted above was a reminder/request for OP to post a solution, and as I did not see any answer posted and no further reason to remove those or other comments on the post, naturally I declined those flags as I tend to err on the side of caution to avoid removing useful content. If you left a comment noting your edit to the question, or have used a custom flag notifying us of your edit, it would have made it clear.

---

Standard **comment flags should be used only when a clear cut *delete* is applicable**. For all other reasons, I recommend a "Other" flag with an explanation of why it should be deleted, especially if:

- edits have been made to the post
- a new answer renders the comment obsolete
- multiple comments are involved
- the context of the flagged comment can be found elsewhere (*another post or page*)
- links in the comment are broken (you can even find a replacement link for us to edit in!)

Don't worry about it, *declined comment flags do not count towards flag bans*<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365732/584192)</sup>. In the future, if your Standard comment flag gets declined, and the particular comment still requires deletion, simply re-flag with a custom explanation!

Upon review of your explanation above, I agree that this comment should be deleted and have removed it.

Comment: Please remind me how you see comment flags? Just (only) the comment in isolation, right? Without the context of the post or comment thread?

Comment: @rene we see the flagged comments (grouped by posts if there are multiple flagged comments). We are able to expand the post to see the post and further expand the rest of the comments on the post. But to see the other posts in the same question, we'll have to click on the permalink. Each flagged comment has delete/edit/dismiss options. We are not able to see who flagged the comment (and thus we lose this context, so we have to solely based on what is presented to us, and assume a random third party flagged it)