# May I have advice on how to use answer-should-be-an-edit-or-comment flags?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, duplicate-answers

I recently saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549061/453435) on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12626288/453435) which [I had answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935567/453435). It appeared to me to be the code from my answer (even copying my until-then unique classname), but with some compile-time attributes removed ([diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/XKcfrvqK); [re-adding whitespace](https://www.diffchecker.com/KIaaobGR)), and [a comment saying that this worked for them but my answer did not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626288/disable-scrolling-in-nstableview/62549061#comment113299293_62549061).

I was concerned that this indicated that my addition of these attributes caused some problem, so [I asked "I pasted my answer into a new Xcode 12.2 project and it worked as expected. What went wrong for you?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626288/disable-scrolling-in-nstableview/62549061#comment114872943_62549061), and [I asked the answer author why they chose to post this instead of upvoting mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626288/disable-scrolling-in-nstableview/62549061#comment114872971_62549061).

While I didn't get any response from the answer author, the commenter who had said that mine didn't work [replied "I don't recall now what the issue was or why I even needed this. Sorry."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626288/disable-scrolling-in-nstableview/62549061#comment114994308_62549061). Since it had been a few days, I took that as confirmation of my suspicion that this answer just copied my code, removed some stuff that didn't affect how it runs, and posted it as their own. So, I downvoted it because it seemed to me that it's not useful (functions the same as my answer, but with no context as to why), and I flagged it since it seems it should possibly be an edit or a comment on my answer which fixes/explains the problems with the compile-time attributes.

That flag was declined with this message, which didn't help me understand why the moderator believes that this answer was best on its own, rather than an edit/comment on mine:

[image: Not an answer – Ben Leggiero Nov 29 at 22:57 declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it]

**Why was this answer better as a standalone, rather than an edit to mine?** **Should I have flagged it as a duplicate instead?** I do wish that the original author had noted why they posted it, but the only non-code text of the answer is "for swift 5.0", so I have no insight into why they posted it.

Comment: Because on it's own it's looks like an answer, and you can't format code in a comment. If it's a correction/adjustment to your answer then it's still a valid answer; though the user should have cited if they copied your answer in there. As for an edit, if it changes the intention of your answer that's also not a good edit. If it *really* should be a comment, instead of a repost of your answer, you would need to use a custom flag so that the mod reading the flag knows that's why you've flagged it.

Comment: I do understand all that. When I mentioned comment, I'd imagined they might say "Your @objc annotation on this class should be removed because ____", not that they'd post formatted code in the comment itself. I flagged it because I suspected that it wasn't a correction/adjustment of my answer, but simply a copy of my answer with some lines removed without explanation.

Comment: *"but simply a copy of my answer with some lines removed without explanation."* That would not be apparent to the mod that reviewed it though. They would simply see that answer, in solitude, and would not see that answer as a "comment", as it (on it only) clearly isn't.

Comment: Probably relevant: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). Note: There's no "duplicate" flag options for Answers.

Comment: I do understand that too. So, should I go back and flag it as a duplicate so they can see the other answer and compare?

Comment: *"... instead of upvoting mine."*, why not ask why they posted it when it's essentially the same answer? There's never any good reason to mention votes in comments

Comment: @Nick that was my intention with that wording. My understanding is that it's better to upvote an existing answer if you think it works, than it is to post that answer again as another. I'll try to be more clear in my comments next time - thanks 

Comment: I don't know, but I love a nice compound adjective!

Comment: Do not stress on single declined flags. If it is really NAA, sometimes other will flag it again. You have the most impact, if you raise 3 other NAA flags (**on not-answers**). You have all the reason to stress if there is a tendency.

Comment: This is very relevant https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/792066

Comment: Thanks, @Braiam! Sucks, but is a little reassuring, to see that I'm not alone in my confusion

Answer (score 15):

*Not an Answer* flags are for, wait for it, posts that are not an answer.

Answers like *I have this problem too!* or *Can you help me solve x?* or *I like the Beatles.* are not answers. Those can be flagged and will be deleted by any reviewer, even by a diamond mod.

If someone copied your answer then by definition that copy is an answer. You've used the wrong flag.

You could/should raise a custom moderator flag and explain that the answer looks a lot like your answer (maybe call it plagiarism but I don't find this particular one a strong case) and doesn't add much value or new angle to the same problem. Explain that an NAA flag is not an option. Then a mod might delete the answer.

You do have delete vote privileges. The safest way is to use those. Downvote, delete vote, leave a comment for context so other 20K-ers can help with the voting, either by visiting the answer or because they watch the [recent delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=) (10K only)

Comment: Thank you! This helps me understand where I went wrong and what action to take both now and in the future

Comment: I will use a custom flag on this one, since I cannot vote to delete this answer since it has a positive score. I wasn't aware of this mechanic until now! 