# Can a moderator un-delete this answer which I think still contains a valid solution?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, deleted-answers, moderators

This concerns https://stackoverflow.com/a/64459725/453435. The original text is as follows:

> i had the same problem with sharepoint 2016 on windows server 2019.
>
> It's helped me: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/not-able-complete-sharepoint-server-2016-installation-windows-server-2019-datacenter
>
> (I installed KB4011244 and after reboot it worked well)

This answer contained a link to the support article where the writer found their answer. **They included the actual solution in their post**, but in parentheses beneath the link, and thus the link's prominence made it appear that the answerer intended the link itself to be the actual answer.

I followed the link and found the solution in the linked page's text. I then edited the post to reduce the link's prominence, and I copied the support article's solution and pasted it into the answer as a quote. Here is the text after my edit:

> I had the same problem with sharepoint 2016 on windows server 2019.
>
> The solution in this support page helped me:
>
> > Install the security update KB4011244 for the 64-bit version of SharePoint Server 2016.
>
> <sup>(from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/not-able-complete-sharepoint-server-2016-installation-windows-server-2019-datacenter)</sup>
>
> I installed KB4011244 and after reboot it worked well

After the edit, I tried to vote to undelete, but since it was deleted by a moderator, the system would not let me cast that vote: [image: A red message saying 'A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted']

**Since this post had answered the question, and now contains the text in the linked webpage, can a moderator un-delete that answer?**

Comment: Might be nitpicking since the question is about SharePoint 2013 with a specific error message and the answer is about SharePoint 2016 with a different error message and a security update specific for 64-bit SharePoint Server 2016. Are you sure it will solve the problem with SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Ideally, as well, the answer would be better if it linked to the page to download the specific KB, rather than a different 3rd party site.

Comment: Alternatively deleting the question seem to be more appropriate as there is nothing programming related in it

Comment: @Security Hound: Why is it out of scope? Aren't [tools commonly used by software developers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) covered?

Comment: @AndrewT. I was under the assumption that answers which are incorrect should still be left undeleted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/453435

Comment: @PeterMortensen That is really a general purpose admin stuff, not coding software, and we specifically have tis close reason:
*"This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline. About professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration This question is more likely to get an answer on Server Fault."*

Comment: Question is closed and deleted now (and not by a mod)

Comment: @Larnu Microsoft has a very bad habit of moving or deleting useful web pages.  Links to Microsoft content go bad distressingly often.

Comment: Though true, it doesn't change my point, @MarkRansom . A direct link to the currently correct URL is far better than a 3rd party site. At least if the URL does change the answer can be edited, where as it's unlikely the the users here will be able to edit a 3rd party site.